# Your requirements could not be resolved to an install-able set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Here's my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "2.*",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-taggable": "^2.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.0",
    "league/url": "3.3.5",
    "illuminate/mail": "5.2.*",
    "sngrl/sphinxsearch": "dev-master",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.3",
    "google/recaptcha": "~1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.1",
    "zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard": "^2.2",
    "florianv/laravel-swap": "^1.0",
    "php-http/message": "^1.4",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
    "vsch/laravel-translation-manager": "~2.1",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.5.0",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^0.4.3",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "skovmand/mailchimp-laravel": "^1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.3",
    "roumen/sitemap": "2.6.*",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
    "illuminate/database": "~5.3",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.3",
    "nesbot/carbon": "~1.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "~5.0",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "~2.7|~3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

When I run the command "composer Install". It works Perfect but when I delete my composer.lock file and then re-run the composer install then I'm getting this error
My PHP Version is - PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - illuminate/database v5.6.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/database v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/database v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/database v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/database v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.45
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.44
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.43
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.42
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.2.41
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.40
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.39
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.38
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.37
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.36
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.35
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.34
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.33
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.32
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.31
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.30
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.29
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.28
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.27
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.26
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.25
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.24
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.23
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.22
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.21
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.20
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.19
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.18
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.17
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
>       - illuminate/database v5.3.0 requires illuminate/container 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
>       - illuminate/database v5.3.16 requires illuminate/container 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
>       - illuminate/database v5.3.23 requires illuminate/container 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
>       - illuminate/database v5.3.4 requires illuminate/container 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.0 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.13 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.17 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.19 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.27 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.36 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.4.9 requires illuminate/container 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.0 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.16 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.17 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.2 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.28 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.33 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - illuminate/database v5.5.34 requires illuminate/container 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35].
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - don't install illuminate/container v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11,
>   v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25,
>   v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32,
>   v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4,
>   v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7,
>   v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
>       - Installation request for illuminate/database ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0,
>   v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16,
>   v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.2,
>   v5.6.3, v5.6.4].

I have tried everything but none of the things are working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your version of `PHP` to `>=7.1`

Comment: `requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.` is pretty clear that you should upgrade your PHP version

Comment: But when I first installed it... It installed perfectly. I think there is some other issue than this.

Comment: `composer install` while using an existing `composer.lock` installs the dependencies that are listed there. They might be outdated. Through deleting the lock file, you re-calculate the dependencies and probably get more recent packages that have new dependencies

Comment: @Nico Haase, I guess this is the issue. Is there any way by which I can delete the composer.lock and when I'll run command composer install, It will install outdated dependencies?

Comment: No, you have to define them specifically if you want them to be in such versions. Or otherwise don't delete the lock if you don't want dependencies to be redefined ;)